# Setting up collation for diacritic-insensitive search with MongoDB C#/.NET Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to implement diacritics-insensitive search with MongoDB C# driver, e.g. when I search for "Joao", it should return all the results containing both "João" and "Joao" (if any).

The following command works on MongoDBCompass, i.e. if I run it against my MongoDB collection (currently only containing a document with "João", none with "Joao"), it will return the correct document:

```
db.profiles.find({FirstName:"Joao"}).collation({locale:"pt", strength: 1})
```

However, when I try to transpose it to C#, it won't work (e. g. doesn't return any result if I search for "Joao", only if I search for "João"):

```
private IFindFluent<ProfessionalProfile, ProfessionalProfile> BuildProfessionalLocationFilter(BaseQuery criteria)
{
    FilterDefinition<ProfessionalProfile> filter = FilterDefinition<ProfessionalProfile>.Empty;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(criteria.SearchWords))
    {
        var searchWords = criteria.SearchWords.ToLower().Trim().Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
        FilterDefinition<ProfessionalProfile> searchWordFilter = FilterDefinition<ProfessionalProfile>.Empty;

        foreach (string searchWord in searchWords)
        {
            var newFilter = Builders<ProfessionalProfile>.Filter.And(Builders<ProfessionalProfile>.Filter.Where(profile =>
                profile.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(searchWord) ||
                profile.LastName.ToLower().Contains(searchWord) ||
                profile.Description.ToLower().Contains(searchWord) ||
                profile.Email.ToLower().Contains(searchWord) ||
                profile.Facebook.ToLower().Contains(searchWord) ||
                profile.Instagram.ToLower().Contains(searchWord) ||
                profile.LinkedIn.ToLower().Contains(searchWord) ||
                profile.Locations.Any(location => 
                location.Name.ToLower().Contains(searchWord) ||
                location.District.Name.ToLower().Contains(searchWord) ||
                location.Council.Name.ToLower().Contains(searchWord)) &&
                !profile.IsDeleted &&
                profile.WizardStep == 6));

            if (searchWordFilter == FilterDefinition<ProfessionalProfile>.Empty)
                searchWordFilter = newFilter;
            else
                searchWordFilter = searchWordFilter | newFilter;
        }

        filter = filter & searchWordFilter;
    }

    IFindFluent<ProfessionalProfile, ProfessionalProfile> findFluent = _professionalCollection.Find(filter);

    findFluent.Options.Collation = new Collation("pt", strength: CollationStrength.Primary);

    //IFindFluent<ProfessionalProfile, ProfessionalProfile> findFluent = _professionalCollection.Find(filter, new FindOptions() { Collation = new Collation("pt", strength: CollationStrength.Primary) } );

    return findFluent;
}
```

Please note that I've also tried the commented line above, with the same (predictable) results.

What could be missing? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

As asked in the comment below by @Đĵ ΝιΓΞΗΛψΚ, I'm adding some information about the profile collection collation.

Mongo shell command:

```
db.getCollectionInfos({ name: 'profiles' })
```

Ouput:

```
[
  {
    name: 'profiles',
    type: 'collection',
    options: {},
    info: {
      readOnly: false,
      uuid: UUID("4606f027-03b1-45e8-bf7f-6c99461db042")
    },
    idIndex: { v: 2, key: [Object], name: '_id_', ns: 'dev.profiles' }
  }
]
```

Comment: Why do you have a ton of fields mentioned in the c# code and no mention of collation?

Comment: I don't know if I'm getting it 100%, but I'm defining collation in the last couple of lines. Do you suggest a different approach?

Comment: can you run this command in mongo shell `db.getCollectionInfos({ name: 'profiles' })` and add the result to your question. i'm interested to see if you created the collection with the correct collation.

Comment: Edited question with the requested command output. Although the collection hasn't been created by myself,  is it needed to explicitly set the collation on Mongo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it took a bit of investigating since documentation on the issue is scarse, but i think i figured out what's happening.

`profile.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(searchWord)` gets translated by the driver to a `$regex` query.

from what i can see, the regex search in mongodb is not collation aware. so you can't use regex functionality to do diacritic insensitive searches.

however, the solution to your requirement is to create a `Text Index` containing all of the fields you want to search in and utilize that index to do a diacritic & case insensitive search for your search words. it will also be the most efficient way to achieve your requirement.

the one limitation of using a text index is that it won't let you search for partial matches of words such as `Jo`. mongodb fulltext search only works on complete words unfortunately.

here's a test program (using mongodb.entities library for brevity):

```js
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Entities;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestApplication
{
    public class ProfessionalProfile : Entity
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public int WizardStep { get; set; }
    }

    public static class Program
    {
        private static async Task Main()
        {
            await DB.InitAsync("test", "localhost");

            await DB.Index<ProfessionalProfile>()
                    .Key(p => p.FirstName, KeyType.Text)
                    .Key(p => p.LastName, KeyType.Text)
                    .CreateAsync();

            await new[] {
                new ProfessionalProfile{ FirstName = "João", LastName = "Balboa", IsDeleted = false, WizardStep = 6},
                new ProfessionalProfile{ FirstName = "Joao", LastName = "Balboa", IsDeleted = false, WizardStep = 6},
            }.SaveAsync();

            IAggregateFluent<ProfessionalProfile> aggregateFluent =
                DB.FluentTextSearch<ProfessionalProfile>(
                    searchType: Search.Full,
                    searchTerm: "Joao Mary John",
                    caseSensitive: false,
                    diacriticSensitive: false)
                .Match(p => !p.IsDeleted && p.WizardStep == 6);

            var result = await aggregateFluent.ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

i'm sure you won't have much trouble translating that to mongo driver code.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Meanwhile I've already used the driver's .Text() + compound text index approach, but I was curious why this wasn't working, as it was the preferred one. I've noticed that using .Contains() added / /is to JSON request, replacing them with " " in compass worked:

`{"$or":[{"FirstName":/joao/is},{"LastName":/joao/is},{"Description":/joao/is},{"Email":/joao/is},{"Facebook":/joao/is},{"Instagram":/joao/is},{"LinkedIn":/joao/is},{"Locations":{"$elemMatch":{"$or":[{"Name":/joao/is},{"District.Name":/joao/is},{"Council.Name":/joao/is}]}},"IsDeleted":{"$ne":true},"WizardStep":6}]}`

Comment: yes `FirstName: "joao"` does equality matching, and `FirstName: /joao/is` does regex matching. equality has collation awareness and regex does not.

Comment: But how to explain that the same request with `"FirstName": /joão/is` works in Compass? It's because in that case there is no need of collation awareness (since there is equality, as the document contains "João")?